# Maintain display:block on an element on mouseover

Tags: jquery

```
  <div id='main'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Feed</legend>
      <div class='user_show_finds'>
        <span>
          <h3>
            product name
          </h3>
          <p>
            <a href="/products/1">Thorpe Obazee</a>

          </p>
        </span>
        <img alt="1331699_summer_shoes" src="/photos/1/1331699_summer.jpg?1299" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

I currently have the above on my html.

```
  $('#main fieldset div.user_show_finds img').hover(
    function(){
      $(this).parent('div').find('span').toggle();
    },
    function(){
      $(this).parent('div').find('span').toggle();
    }
  );
```

I have the above in my javascript file.

It works. but the problem is that when I hover on the span(the one that becomes visible when hovering on the img), the span returns to `display:none`. I understand that it loses it because it mouses over another element.

How would I NOT lose the `display:block`?

UPDATE:

```
  $('#main fieldset div.user_show_finds span').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css({'display':'block'});
    },
    function(){}
  );
```

This seems to fix it but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I don't undersand completely, but isn't this because SPAN is default an inline element (display: inline)?

Comment: did u try with setting default style on `span`

Comment: changed span to block in my css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By defining what you want the semantics to be instead.

Perhaps you want it so that the user should mouse-over the image to see the span, then it'll disappear when the user moves into and then out of the spam.

Perhaps you want it so that the span disappears if the cursor has left the image *and* has not moved onto the span (which requires that they are touching, incidentally). You could accomplish this by setting eventhandlers on the span, too, and keeping some tracking variables to see which handlers have fired and thus where the mouse cursor is. Then build your logic as desired.

Comment: Yes, I have done that as I showed on the updated answer. What I need to know if there is a cleaner way to do that in the first function.

Comment: @Thorpe: No; at present you only have an event handler for the image. You'd need one for the span, too. TBH the fix you put in your edit looks OK to me.